# How to get the new key pushed on firebase?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

Dears,

I don't know how to get he new key pushed in firebase.
This is my simple example code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('mychild').push().set(
            <String, String>{
              'hello': 'world',
            });
```

How can I get the key of this element pushed?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this :

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference(); 
String newkey = rootRef.child('mychild').push().key;
rootRef.child('mychild').child(newKey).set(<String, String>{'hello': 'world',});
```

Comment: Thanks @florex

The correct code would be:

`code
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
        String newkey=rootRef.reference().child('mychild').push().key;
        print (newkey);
        rootRef.child('mychild').child(newkey).set(
            <String, String>{
              'hello': 'world',
            });
`

Thanks :)